# How to create user model with nested map field for cloud firestore with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create a nested field with the type of map. **'usersName'** is the field that has the type of map, contain **'firstName'** and **'lastName'**. Here is the image:
[image]
If you need a source code, tell me. Thank you

**user_model.dart**

```
class User {
  String id;
  String name;
  String email;
  String password;
  String phone;

  User({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.email,
    required this.password,
    required this.phone,
  });

  //and i dont know how to make it work
}
```

Comment: Yes, is recommended to show the source code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `UserName` class with `firstName` and `lastName` variables and then on your `User` class you change your `name` from `String` to `UserName`.

```
class User {
 String id;
 UserName name;
 String email;
 String password;
 String phone;

 User({
   required this.id,
   required this.name,
   required this.email,
   required this.password,
   required this.phone,
 });
}

class UserName {
   String firstName;
   String lastName;
   UserName({
      required this.firstName,
      required this.lastName,
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this change and you will be able to receive it as you want:

```
class User {
  String id;
  Map<String, String> name;
  String email;
  String password;
  String phone;

  User({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.email,
    required this.password,
    required this.phone,
  });

  //and i dont know how to make it work
}
```

More information on dart Maps: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#maps

Answer (score 0):

I agree that setting the `name` property as `Map` is the way to go. For example, you have your user name as follow:

```
var name = {firstName: "Joe", lastName: "Smith"}
```

Create your `User` class as above then create method to convert your properties accordingly. Here I created `toMap()` to return a Map object of the User.

```
class User {
  String id;
  Map<String, String> name;
  String email;
  String password;
  String phone;

  User({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.email,
    required this.password,
    required this.phone,
  });

  // if you intend to store this User object into a database/storage
  // that requires Map object
   Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    // convert Map to String
    var fullName = name.toString();
  
    return {
      'id': id,
      // String key, String value
      'name': fullName,
      ...
    };
  }

}
```

Comment: thanks man, but now I didn't use firebase anymore because now I have to learn python for college exam.